# Setting permissions on NTFS Fileshare with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, ntfs, system-administration

My script in a nutshell should create 5 Folders, 1 root level folder, 3 2nd level folders, and 1 3rd level folder.

Permissions are granted at the 2nd level, either ReadWrite or ReadOnly.  No user should be able to create anything within the second level or delete a second level.

I seem to be having issues with `Set-Acl` and permissions.  I'm wondering if there's a better way to script this out that I don't need elevated privileges for.  Our DA's can run the script fine, and I can do the folder and security group creation manually but its tedious and prone to errors.  Any insight into what I'm doing wrong or how I could do it better would be appreciated.

```cs
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$path = "\\earth\data\group\"
$newFolderName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Name of New Folder"
$newFolderFull = $path + $newFolderName
Write-Output "New Folder will be: $newFolderFull"
$confirm = Read-Host "Confirm? Y/N"
if (!(($confirm) -ne "y")) {
    Write-Output "Create AD Groups"
    $groupNamePGroup = "P_$newFolderName"
    $groupNameAdminRW = "EG-$newFolderName-Admin-RW"
    $groupNameAdminRF = "EG-$newFolderName-Admin-RF"
    $groupNameEveryoneRW = "EG-$newFolderName-Everyone-RW"
    $groupNameEveryoneRF = "EG-$newFolderName-Everyone-RF"
    $groupNameScannedDocsRW = "EG-$newFolderName-ScannedDocs-RW"

    New-ADGroup $groupNamePGroup -samAccountName $groupNamePGroup -GroupScope DomainLocal -path "OU=SecurityGroups,OU=Metro,DC=metrogr,DC=org"
    New-ADGroup $groupNameAdminRW -samAccountName $groupNameAdminRW -GroupScope DomainLocal -path "OU=SecurityGroups,OU=Metro,DC=metrogr,DC=org"
    New-ADGroup $groupNameAdminRF -samAccountName $groupNameAdminRF -GroupScope DomainLocal -path "OU=SecurityGroups,OU=Metro,DC=metrogr,DC=org"
    New-ADGroup $groupNameEveryoneRW -samAccountName $groupNameEveryoneRW -GroupScope DomainLocal -path "OU=SecurityGroups,OU=Metro,DC=metrogr,DC=org"
    New-ADGroup $groupNameEveryoneRF -samAccountName $groupNameEveryoneRF -GroupScope DomainLocal -path "OU=SecurityGroups,OU=Metro,DC=metrogr,DC=org"
    New-ADGroup $groupNameScannedDocsRW -samAccountName $groupNameScannedDocsRW -GroupScope DomainLocal -path "OU=SecurityGroups,OU=Metro,DC=metrogr,DC=org"

    Write-Output "Add Folder.."
    New-Item $newFolderFull -ItemType Directory
    New-Item $newFolderFull\Admin -ItemType Directory
    New-Item $newFolderFull\Everyone -ItemType Directory
    New-Item $newFolderFull\ScannedDocs -ItemType Directory
    New-Item $newFolderFull\Everyone\ScannedDocs -ItemType Directory

    Write-Output "Remove Inheritance.."
    icacls $newFolderFull /inheritance:d
    icacls $newFolderFull\Admin /inheritance:d
    icacls $newFolderFull\Everyone /inheritance:d
    icacls $newFolderFull\Everyone\ScannedDocs /inheritance:d
    #icacls $newFolderFull\ScannedDocs /inheritance:d

    # Rights
    $readOnly = [Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"ReadAndExecute"
    $readWrite = [Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Write, DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles,ReadAndExecute"

    # Inheritance
    $inheritanceFlag = [Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
    # Propagation
    $propagationFlag = [Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None
    # User
    $PUserRF = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($groupNamePGroup)
    $AdminUserRW = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($groupnameAdminRW)
    $AdminUserRF = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($groupnameAdminRF)
    $EveryoneUserRW = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($groupnameEveryoneRW)
    $EveryoneUserRF = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($groupnameEveryoneRF)
    $ScannedDocsUserRW = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($groupnameScannedDocsRW)
    # Type
    $type = [Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow

    #Add Group membership
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupNamePGroup -Members $groupNameAdminRW,$groupNameAdminRF,$groupNameEveryoneRW,$groupNameEveryoneRF,$groupNameScannedDocsRW
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupNameEveryoneRW -Members NDPSSCAN
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupNameScannedDocsRW -Members NDPSSCAN

    # ACL
    $accessControlEntryDefault = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule @("Domain Users", $readOnly, $inheritanceFlag, $propagationFlag, $type)
    $accessControlRootEntryRF = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule @($PUserRF, $readOnly, $inheritanceFlag, $propagationFlag, $type)
    $accessControlAdminEntryRW = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule @($AdminUserRW, $readWrite, $inheritanceFlag, $propagationFlag, $type)
    $accessControlAdminEntryRF = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule @($AdminUserRF, $readOnly, $inheritanceFlag, $propagationFlag, $type)
    $accessControlEveryoneEntryRW = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule @($EveryoneUserRW, $readWrite, $inheritanceFlag, $propagationFlag, $type)
    $accessControlEveryoneEntryRF = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule @($EveryoneUserRF, $readOnly, $inheritanceFlag, $propagationFlag, $type)
    $accessControlScannedDocsEntryRW = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule @($ScannedDocsUserRW, $readWrite, $inheritanceFlag, $propagationFlag, $type)

    $objACL = Get-Acl $newFolderFull
    $objACL.RemoveAccessRuleAll($accessControlEntryDefault)
    $objACL.AddAccessRule($accessControlRootEntryRF)
    Set-Acl $newFolderFull $objACL

    $objACL = Get-Acl $newFolderFull\Admin
    $objACL.RemoveAccessRuleAll($accessControlEntryDefault)
    $objACL.AddAccessRule($accessControlAdminEntryRW)
    $objACL.AddAccessRule($accessControlAdminEntryRF)
    Set-Acl $newFolderFull\Admin $objACL

    $objACL = Get-Acl $newFolderFull\Everyone
    $objACL.RemoveAccessRuleAll($accessControlEntryDefault)
    $objACL.AddAccessRule($accessControlEveryoneEntryRW)
    $objACL.AddAccessRule($accessControlEveryoneEntryRF)
    Set-Acl $newFolderFull\Everyone $objACL

    $objACL = Get-Acl $newFolderFull\ScannedDocs
    $objACL.RemoveAccessRuleAll($accessControlEntryDefault)
    $objACL.AddAccessRule($accessControlScannedDocsEntryRW)
    Set-Acl $newFolderFull\ScannedDocs $objACL
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're facing, but one optimization would obviously be wrapping the code that creates an ACE and reads/modifies an ACL in custom functions, thus avoiding spaghetti code. As for needing elevated privileges: you can modify ACLs if the existing ACLs allow you to do so. If they don't elevation *is* required. And no, there is no way around that. If there was that would be a *huge* security hole.

Comment: Set-ACL : The process does not possess the 'SeSecurityPrivilege' privilege which is required for this operation.
At C:\Powershell\FolderCreationStart.ps1:85 char:3
+   Set-ACL $newFolderFull\Everyone $objACL
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\earth\data\group\zzRobertTest\Everyone:String) [Set-Acl], PrivilegeNotHeldException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.AccessControl.PrivilegeNotHeldException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand

This is the error I keep getting.

Comment: Well, that error message doesn't leave much to explain, does it?

Comment: `PermissionDenied` - Check your local policies because your account doesn't have permissions. Specifically, the `Take ownership of files or other objects` policy.

Comment: $objACL = Get-ACL $newFolderFull\ScannedDocs
  $objACL.RemoveAccessRuleAll($accessControlEntryDefault)
  $objACL.AddAccessRule($accessControlScannedDocsEntryRW)
  #Set-ACL $newFolderFull\ScannedDocs $objACL
  (Get-Item -Path $newFolderFull\ScannedDocs).SetAccessControl($objACL)


Saw someone else who was having the same issues, they could do the folder creation and security groups manually but not with Powershell.  Using the SetAccessControl my script does what it needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

`SetAccessControl($objACL)` worked for me.

`Set-ACL` didn't work as my account didn't have elevated permissions.